# Japanese/Chinese Language character tolower/toupper function gets failed when using UTF-16

Tags: c++11, utf-8, localization, utf-16

I need to sort some string of Japanese/Chinese string. I am using UTF16 format here. to start with sorting, i am first normalising its character by using tolower function. but this function giving me same reply (val:31) for some characters. I tried using toupper function as well but there was no change.If I first convert UTF-16 to UTF-8 function then things start working correctly.Could any one help me what I am doing wrong.This bug is limited to these language only.

If I convert UTF-16 to UTF-8 then things starting working correctly.

Comment: The [`tolower`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower) and [`touper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper) function only work with 8 or 7 bit fixed size encodings, in the current locale. So it can't handle either UTF-16 *nor* UTF-8 properly.

Comment: so what should i do then? I want to use normalisation here.

Comment: There are a few Unicode handling libraries around which you can use, for example [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org).

Comment: Could you help me here to understand why its not happening with UTF-16/UTF-8? or why its not possible.